# How can I replace newline button with done button in an EditText

Tags: java, android, xml

I am trying to make my EditText instead of using `newline` button to display a `Done` button.

Typical problem with many questions on SO, however most recommend using `singleLine="true"` which is deprecated.

Here is my XML that displays the EditText:

```
// Other XML
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:digits="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789-_"
        android:hint="@string/character_name_hint"
        android:imeOptions="actionDone"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:textStyle="italic" />
 // Rest of the XML...
```

However using `android:imeOptions="actionDone"` doesn't work, neither is setting it programmatically `name.setImeOptions(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE);` I have tried it on two different emulators and a live device, API levels ranging from 21 to 26, I have used every single combination of `maxLines`, `inputType` and `imeOptions` to no avail.

The button will simply not change to "Done". However using `android:singleLine="true"` will instantly fix that....

For now I don't care about what it needs to be done after clicking, I simply want to change button to "Done"

Answer (score 0):

Set an `ImeOptions` and `ImeActionLabel` to your `EditText`.

**Like:**

```
name.setImeOptions(KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN);
name.setImeActionLabel("DONE", KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER);
```

Then add a `setOnKeyListener` for the click event of **Done** button.

```
name.setOnKeyListener((v, keyCode, event) -> {
    if ((event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) && (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)) {
            // your code goes here...
            return true;
    }

    return false;
});
```

Hope this help!